# Simple function in Grapher?

Tags: macos, grapher

I am trying to have just a simple function -> *f*(*x*, *y*) = *x* + *y*
This is in a 3D default graphing environment.

Is this possible, or do I need to use a different graphing tool?

I want this function to be accessible in other equations/functions

Comment: Not sure about the accessibility from other equations and how much you will ultimately like how it looks because Grapher is a bit old but it can do 3D. Just choose 3D Graph/Default as New Graph when you launch the app and enter z=x+y as the equation.

Comment: @Alper This has the problem of being inaccessible and not allowing varied-argument equations.

Comment: @CATboardBETA Grapher is very old and not intended to be more than a basic tool for simple tasks. It seems like you are trying to do serious work. There are a great number of third-party graphing solutions available, many of which are free and open source. Is there a reason that you must use Grapher?

Comment: @pion No. I'll let you in on my real intentions: I want to use grapher kind of like a shader tool like ShaderToy, but without having to deal with the raw GLSL (one of my least favorite languages). That's my preferred sort of interface, and it seemed like an alright choice. If you know of a better one, please enlighten me.

Comment: @CATboardBETA One suggestion that comes to mind is Mathics https://mathics.org

Answer (score 1):

Just open Grapher and select 3D Graphs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work. I want to be able to reference it in other equations (this equation I gave is a huge oversimplification, real one is much larger)

Comment: try to give me the other eq. then

Comment: it's a variation of the Perlin noise formula, layered 15 times. I'm not sending it here, especially without MathJax

Comment: My suggestion is to use another software properly made for that such as Matlab for numerical analysis or [WolframApha](http://wolframalpha.com) free website for analytical models .